# refreshing the page in React manually when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm building a basic CRUD application with the MERN stack with User Authentication.
When I submit the ƒorm to add a post, I constantly have to refresh the page, in order to see it. The Post does get saved in the database, and I see it in the Redux devtools.  Here is my code...

// Submit form

```
const PostForm = ({history}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('')
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('')

    /*const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
    const {loading, error, message, userInfo} = userLogin*/

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const post = {
            title,
            imageUrl,
            description,
        }
        dispatch(addPost(post))
        history.push('/profile')
    }

    return (
        <FormContainer>
            <h1 className='py-3'>Add a Tech Post</h1>
            {/* {message && <Message variant='danger'>{message}</Message>}
            {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
            {loading && <Loader/>}*/}
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <Form.Group className='py-2' controlId='title'>
                    <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type='title'
                        placeholder='Enter title'
                        value={title}
                        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                    >
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId='imageUrl'>
                    <Form.Label>Image URL</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='Enter imageUrl'
                        value={imageUrl}
                        onChange={(e) => setImageUrl(e.target.value)}
                    >
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId='ControlTextarea1'>
                    <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        as="textarea"
                        placeholder='Enter description'
                        value={description}
                        onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <br/>
                <Button type='submit' variant='success'>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </FormContainer>
    );
```

// all posts and profile

```
 const Profile = ({location, history}) => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(null)
    const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(false)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails)
    const {loading, error, user} = userDetails

    const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
    const {userInfo} = userLogin

    const userUpdateProfile = useSelector((state) => state.userUpdateProfile)
    const {success} = userUpdateProfile

    const postList = useSelector((state) => state.postList)
    const {loading: loadingPosts, error: errorPosts, posts} = postList


    useEffect(() => {
        if (!userInfo) {
            history.push('/login')
        } else {
            if (!user || !user.name || success) {
                dispatch({type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET})
                dispatch(getAllPosts())
                dispatch(getUserDetails('profile'))
            } else {
                setName(user.name)
                setEmail(user.email)
            }
        }
    }, [dispatch, history, userInfo, user])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            setMessage('Passwords do not match')
        } else {
            setUpdated(true)
            dispatch(updateUserProfile({id: user._id, name, email, password}))
        }
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <h2 className='py-3'>User Profile</h2>
                    {updated && <Message variant='success'>Profile Updated</Message>}
                    {message && <Message variant='danger'>{message}</Message>}
                    {loading ? (
                        <Loader/>
                    ) : error ? (
                        <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                    ) : (
                        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                            <Form.Group controlId='name'>
                                <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type='name'
                                    placeholder='Enter name'
                                    value={name}
                                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                >
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group controlId='email'>
                                <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type='email'
                                    placeholder='Enter email'
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                >
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group controlId='password'>
                                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type='password'
                                    placeholder='Enter password'
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                >
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group controlId='confirmPassword'>
                                <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type='password'
                                    placeholder='Confirm password'
                                    value={confirmPassword}
                                    onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                                >
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Button type='submit' variant='success'>
                                Update
                            </Button>
                        </Form>

                    )}
                </Col>

                <Col md={9}>
                    <h2 className='my-3'>My Posts</h2>
                    {loadingPosts ? <Loader/> : errorPosts ?
                        <Message variant='danger'>{errorPosts}</Message> : (
                            <Table striped bordered hover responsive className='table-sm'>
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>TITLE</th>
                                    <th/>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                {posts.map(pst => (
                                    <tr key={pst._id}>
                                        <td>{pst._id}</td>
                                        <td>{pst.title}</td>
                                        <LinkContainer to={`/post/${pst._id}`}>
                                            <Button className='btn-sm' variant='light'>
                                                Details
                                            </Button>
                                        </LinkContainer>
                                    </tr>
                                ))}
                                </tbody>
                            </Table>
                        )}
                    <LinkContainer to={'/postForm'}>
                        <div className='text-right mb-5'>
                            <Button variant='light' className='mx-5'>Add Post</Button>
                        </div>
                    </LinkContainer>

                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
```

Comment: How does `addPost(post)` and `getAllPosts()` handle your async requests, i.e. thunk, redux-observable, redux-logic, redux-saga, etc? Without knowing how you are handling these requests what I think is happening here is you call `dispatch(addPost(post))` to add a post via an API call (I assume) and immediately route to `Profile` which calls `dispatch(getAllPosts())`, this creates a race condition as there is no logic to wait for the `addPost(post)` actions related async request to complete before calling `getAllPosts()`.

Comment: @JacobSmit There is a Express API on the backend, they both are individual request to different end points  with ASYNC AWAIT with redux thunk.

Comment: the thunk may be async / await, but the dispatched call does not wait for the thunk to be finished, so it would immediately go to the profile component and load the list while it is still in the process of adding the new item.

Comment: @JacobSmit So how can we solve this issue, meaning what can I do in order not to have to refresh the page, every time I add a new post.  What other,  or more information would you need from me ? If it would be possible to help me.

Comment: I think a basic status of the `addPost` flow would probably cover you, at the start of your `addPost` fire an action to set a state value that you are currently in the progress of adding an item. Once everything is done, or if an error is encountered, fire off another action to set this state value back to the finished state. In your form component you can then use a `useEffect` with some logic to fire off the `history.push`. To make this look a little nicer to users you could also consider showing some form of saving notification depending on how long it takes.